# GUI: How can I find out if certain Unicode characters are supported?

Tags: java, swing, unicode, fonts, look-and-feel

I noticed that Metal L&F doesn't support certain arrow characters from Unicode, while Nimbus and GTK L&Fs do support them.

*Unsupported characters are just displayed as: `...`*

Can I

1. either look up (manually), which L&F supports which Unicode chars,
2. or find it out at runtime?

**EDIT:** Or, should it only depend on the L&F's default font, my question perhaps should be:
*"how do I find out, which Java font supports which Unicode characters?"*

Comment: I'm not an expert, but it may be due to the default font Metal/Ocean uses.

Comment: I am very certain it's the font that determines which characters are supported.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the `canDisplay` method to test if a `java.awt.Font` object can display a given character.
You can typically get the font from GUI components using the `getFont()` method.

Comment: Great! That's it!   http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#canDisplay%28char%29

Answer (score 2):

If you know which unicode block contains the arrows you need, you can look it up [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/intl/font.html). Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a page for newer JDK's.

Comment: Unfortunately, the link is now broken.

Answer (score 1):

Using this piece of code you use almost every Unicode 
ta.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI Emoji", 1, 20));