# Filtering characters missing from the user’s font in Java

Tags: java, unicode, fonts, filter, non-printable

I want to build a somewhat simple  table with Java (as an exercise) to check for the existence of legal printable Unicode code point in the end-user’s font. Because some fonts cannot print valid code points,  I have to know which printable code points the user’s font is nevertheless missing and so cannot print.

For example, if a font supports only Latin characters, I cannot print Greek characters using it, let alone Japanese characters. Unicode says they’re all printable, but the user’s font may not be good enough.

After a little research I’ve been able to print most of the characters in Eclipse (by adjusing the Encoding). However I still have a bunch of unknown/unprintable characters in my output, in that when I look at the output I see all these  empty rectangles for some of my printable characters.

I’ve tried filtering them but I can’t find any way to do it. FYI I’m basically just setting a character's value to 50, 100 or 1000, then incremeningt it via a `for` loop from there to check what characters I can or cannot (or should not?) print.

Can anyone give me some hints on where to start here?

Comment: Start with the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220547/printable-char-in-java

Comment: Define “not printable.” Do you mean characters that are not supposed to have any visible rendering (control characters), or do you mean characters that lack a glyph in the font being used? Also define “character.” Do you mean a code unit, a code point, or a code point assigned to a character? (“Java characters” as such as code units.)

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela It's worse than that.  Sometimes a single user-visible character (read, a *grapheme*, or an *extended grapheme cluster* in Unicode parlance) comprises multiple code points, such as when combining marks and other Grapheme_Extend code points are involved.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java GUI: can I find out if certain Unicode characters are supported?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557597/java-gui-can-i-find-out-if-certain-unicode-characters-are-supported)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your task is actually a little more complex than encoding because the font that you are trying to print from makes a big difference in the output. I.e. not all fonts support the same set of characters. In fact, the support of character ranges [differs wildly from font to font](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_font).

That said, your problem now becomes: How do I detect whether a certain font supports a given character? And [that question has been asked and answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557597/java-gui-can-i-find-out-if-certain-unicode-characters-are-supported)... [See here for the Java doc of the canDisplay](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#canDisplay%28char%29) function which is a member of [the Font class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html).

Answer (score 2):

It is unclear what you actually and precisely mean here. If you plan to play by the numbers, then [Annex C of Unicode Technical Standard #18 on *Unicode Regular Expressions*](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Compatibility_Properties) gives the concrete suggestion that a “printable” code point be defined as any code point that has the `print` property, where that property is defined to be

- `\p{print}`    means `[[\p{graph}\p{blank}]&&[^\p{gc=Control}]]`
- `\p{graph}`    means `[^\p{Whitespace}\p{gc=Control}\p{gc=Surrogate}\p{gc=Unassigned}]`
- `\p{blank}`    means `[\p{Whitespace}&&[^\N{LF}\N{VT}\N{FF}\N{CR}\N{NEL}\p{gc=Line_Separator}\{gc=Paragraph_Separator}]`

Or, [as the Java 1.7 `Pattern` class documents these](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), provided you compile the pattern with [the new-to-Java7 Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS) flag enabled:

- `\p{Graph}`   A visible character: `[^\p{IsWhite_Space}\p{gc=Cc}\p{gc=Cs}\p{gc=Cn}]`
- `\p{Print}`   A printable character: `[\p{Graph}\p{Blank}&&[^\p{Cntrl}]]`
- `\p{Blank}`   A space or a tab: `[\p{IsWhite_Space}&&[^\p{gc=Zl}\p{gc=Zp}\x0a\x0b\x0c\x0d * \x85]]`
- `\p{Cntrl}`   A control character: `\p{gc=Cc}`
- `\p{XDigit}`  A hexadecimal digit: `[\p{gc=Nd}\p{IsHex_Digit}]`
- `\p{Space}`   A whitespace character: `\p{IsWhite_Space}`

### On ‘Printable’ Characters

If you just use something reasonable like Java’s `(?U)\p{print}` pattern property (or the equivalent from the `Character` class), then you still have some “interesting” decisions to make.

Consider each of these code points:

```
U+000007 gc=Cc columns=0 print=0 graph=0  ALERT
U+000008 gc=Cc columns=0 print=0 graph=0  BACKSPACE
U+000009 gc=Cc columns=0 print=0 graph=0  CHARACTER TABULATION
U+00000C gc=Cc columns=0 print=0 graph=0  FORM FEED (FF)
U+00000D gc=Cc columns=0 print=0 graph=0  CARRIAGE RETURN (CR)
U+000020 gc=Zs columns=1 print=1 graph=0  SPACE
U+000021 gc=Po columns=1 print=1 graph=1  EXCLAMATION MARK
U+000041 gc=Lu columns=1 print=1 graph=1  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A
U+000061 gc=Ll columns=1 print=1 graph=1  LATIN SMALL LETTER A
U+000080 gc=Cc columns=0 print=0 graph=0  PADDING CHARACTER
U+000085 gc=Cc columns=0 print=0 graph=0  NEXT LINE (NEL)
U+00008D gc=Cc columns=0 print=0 graph=0  REVERSE LINE FEED
U+0000AB gc=Pi columns=1 print=1 graph=1  LEFT-POINTING DOUBLE ANGLE QUOTATION MARK
U+0000AD gc=Cf columns=0 print=1 graph=1  SOFT HYPHEN
U+0002B0 gc=Lm columns=1 print=1 graph=1  MODIFIER LETTER SMALL H
U+0002C6 gc=Lm columns=1 print=1 graph=1  MODIFIER LETTER CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT
U+000302 gc=Mn columns=0 print=1 graph=1  COMBINING CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT
U+00036A gc=Mn columns=0 print=1 graph=1  COMBINING LATIN SMALL LETTER H
U+001100 gc=Lo columns=2 print=1 graph=1  HANGUL CHOSEONG KIYEOK
U+002028 gc=Zl columns=0 print=0 graph=0  LINE SEPARATOR
U+002029 gc=Zp columns=0 print=0 graph=0  PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR
U+00202B gc=Cf columns=0 print=1 graph=1  RIGHT-TO-LEFT EMBEDDING
U+00202F gc=Zs columns=1 print=1 graph=0  NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE
U+002060 gc=Cf columns=0 print=1 graph=1  WORD JOINER
U+002061 gc=Cf columns=0 print=1 graph=1  FUNCTION APPLICATION
U+002062 gc=Cf columns=0 print=1 graph=1  INVISIBLE TIMES
U+002064 gc=Cf columns=0 print=1 graph=1  INVISIBLE PLUS
U+002EC1 gc=So columns=2 print=1 graph=1  CJK RADICAL TIGER
U+002F0B gc=So columns=2 print=1 graph=1  KANGXI RADICAL EIGHT
U+003000 gc=Zs columns=2 print=1 graph=0  IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE
U+003008 gc=Ps columns=2 print=1 graph=1  LEFT ANGLE BRACKET
U+00300A gc=Ps columns=2 print=1 graph=1  LEFT DOUBLE ANGLE BRACKET
U+00300C gc=Ps columns=2 print=1 graph=1  LEFT CORNER BRACKET
U+00302B gc=Mn columns=0 print=1 graph=1  IDEOGRAPHIC RISING TONE MARK
U+003030 gc=Pd columns=2 print=1 graph=1  WAVY DASH
U+003037 gc=So columns=2 print=1 graph=1  IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH LINE FEED SEPARATOR SYMBOL
U+003041 gc=Lo columns=2 print=1 graph=1  HIRAGANA LETTER SMALL A
U+00E000 gc=Co columns=1 print=1 graph=1 <unnamed codepoint in blk=Private_Use_Area>
U+00F8FF gc=Co columns=1 print=1 graph=1 <unnamed codepoint in blk=Private_Use_Area>
U+00FB1E gc=Mn columns=0 print=1 graph=1  HEBREW POINT JUDEO-SPANISH VARIKA
U+00FE00 gc=Mn columns=0 print=1 graph=1  VARIATION SELECTOR-1
U+00FE23 gc=Mn columns=0 print=1 graph=1  COMBINING DOUBLE TILDE RIGHT HALF
U+00FE58 gc=Pd columns=2 print=1 graph=1  SMALL EM DASH
U+00FE77 gc=Lo columns=1 print=1 graph=1  ARABIC FATHA MEDIAL FORM
U+00FEFF gc=Cf columns=0 print=1 graph=1  ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE
U+00FF06 gc=Po columns=2 print=1 graph=1  FULLWIDTH AMPERSAND
U+00FFFA gc=Cf columns=0 print=1 graph=1  INTERLINEAR ANNOTATION SEPARATOR
U+00FFFD gc=So columns=1 print=1 graph=1  REPLACEMENT CHARACTER
U+01B000 gc=Lo columns=2 print=1 graph=1  KATAKANA LETTER ARCHAIC E
U+01D165 gc=Mc columns=1 print=1 graph=1  MUSICAL SYMBOL COMBINING STEM
U+01D167 gc=Mn columns=0 print=1 graph=1  MUSICAL SYMBOL COMBINING TREMOLO-1
U+100002 gc=Co columns=1 print=1 graph=1 <unnamed codepoint in blk=Supplementary_Private_Use_Area-B>
```

Some of them are quite conditional as to what, and perhaps even whether, they print. For example, what does U+F8FF’s ‹› look like to you?

Then you have to decide how to handle tabs and backspace.

Plus you will have to consider the various `\p{Grapheme_Extend}` code points used to build up a Unicode  *extended grapheme cluster*; that is, a **user-visible character**.  Not all of these are nonspacing marks. In fact, some aren’t marks at all, but letters! Some are not printable characters at all, and yet they change the printable `\p{Grapheme_Base}` character to which they are ineluctably attached; consider just as one example the variation selectors.

## Warning

Which brings us to a critically important point that is far too often forgotten by would-be Java programmers, and even when not wholly forgotten, is usually underappreciated.

Always, always, always remember that ***Java characters are not Unicode characters!***   There are two reasonable definitions of a Unicode character, and Java gives you neither.  Here are the two reasonable definitions:

- If a character is a character in the *programmer-visible* sense, then a character is a Unicode code point.  This is what `.` matches in the regex engine, for example, no matter whether you use Sun’s or ICU’s.
- If a character is a character in the *user-visible* sense, then a character is a Unicode extended grapheme cluster. This is what `\X` matches in the (ICU not Sun) regex engine.

A Java so-called “character” is a low-level, breaks-the-abstract 2-byte element of a variable-width UTF-16 representation of an actual Unicode code point. It is neither an abstract code point nor an abstract grapheme.  It is not an abstract *anything.*  A Java `char` is a violation of the envelope of abstraction.

Yes, some Java classes give you a `codePointAt` interface, and you should absolutely use those wherever those are available. But in many ways that it takes too long to explain here, **Java is fundamentally broken in its character abstraction** — because it doesn’t have one.

This makes working with Unicode characters and strings at best error-prone in Java, and often next to impossible.

Good luck.